# at the last minute vs. until the last minute

Tags: meaning, usage

Do you see any difference in meaning and usage in the following phrases:

- at the last minute
- until the last minute

To provide more details, here are two examples:

1. Do you usually book your holidays a long time in advance, or at the last minute?
2. Are you someone who puts things off until the last minute?

Comment: Absolutely. You **do** something "at the last minute", and you **leave** something "until the last minute."

Answer (score -1):

"at" can be used when the action happens in a definite time.
"until" - when the action prolongs for a continuous period of time.